# Doing something that was started more recently and for a shorter period than another person

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I'm thinking about a situation like this:

- John started working at this company 2 years ago.
- Mary started working at this company 1 year ago.

So, I want to say that Mary is working at this company having started "more recently" and (thus) "during a shorter period" than John. How could I convey that idea in a correct and concise way?

Comment: use the word seniority?

Comment: @WillowRex: Thanks for the tip. Yes, the word "seniority" may help here. How would you use it in this particular context?

Comment: John has more seniority than Mary; Mary has less seniority than John.

Comment: John has more seniority than Mary. Or, Mray has less seniority than John. If you need to say how long, add that in. John has a year's more senority than Mary, who started last January.

Comment: @WillowRex: Sounds good :-) If you wish, write an answer saying that and I will gladly accept it (today or tomorrow). Also thanks to John Feltz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John has more seniority than Mary. Or, Mary has less seniority than John. If you need to say how long, add that in. John has a year's more senority than Mary, who started last January.